# error: illegal start of expression in my Android studio code

Tags: java, android

I wrote some code in Android Studio for downloading content from the web. The build shows

> "error: illegal start of expression"

and I'm not able to figure out the error. While checking for the error, I was asked to search for missing semi-colons and opening or closing braces. I have checked both and can't find any error.

The code is:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
    {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try{

                url= new URL(urls[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                int data = reader.read();

                while(data!=-1){
                    char current = (char) data;
                    result + = current;
                    data = reader.read();
                }

                return result;

            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }


        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        String result = null;
        try {
      //       result = task.execute("http://www.posh24.se/kandisar").get();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the error output (as-is) as well as your code, as it likely indicates what part of the sourcecode the issue is within.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have space between  `result + = current;` try below line

```
result += current;
```